# simile timeline. problem with XML file

Tags: javascript, xml, timeline

I was searching through the web how to do time lines. I found this one that I like: http://www.simile-widgets.org/timeline/

So I try to follow their tutorial, which can be found here: http://simile.mit.edu/wiki/How_to_Create_Timelines

I following the tutorial so the code is the same but here it goes:

```
<script>
   var tl;
function onLoad() {
var eventSource = new Timeline.DefaultEventSource();

var bandInfos = [
Timeline.createBandInfo({
    eventSource:    eventSource,
    date:           "Jun 28 2006 00:00:00 GMT",

    width:          "70%", 
    intervalUnit:   Timeline.DateTime.MONTH, 
    intervalPixels: 100
}),
Timeline.createBandInfo({
    eventSource:    eventSource,
    date:           "Jun 28 2006 00:00:00 GMT",

    width:          "30%", 
    intervalUnit:   Timeline.DateTime.YEAR, 
    intervalPixels: 200
})
  ];
bandInfos[1].syncWith = 0;
bandInfos[1].highlight = true;

tl = Timeline.create(document.getElementById("my-timeline"), bandInfos);
Timeline.loadXML("test.xml", function(xml, url) { eventSource.loadXML(xml, url); });

}

var resizeTimerID = null;
function onResize() {
if (resizeTimerID == null) {
    resizeTimerID = window.setTimeout(function() {
        resizeTimerID = null;
        tl.layout();
    }, 500);
}
}

</script>
<body onload="onLoad();" onresize="onResize();">
<div id="my-timeline" style="height: 150px; border: 1px solid #aaa"></div>
</body>
```

And the test.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
 <?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="/TBDBsite/media/timeline.css"?>
 <data>
<event 
    start="May 28 2006 09:00:00 GMT"
    end="Jun 15 2006 09:00:00 GMT"
    isDuration="true"
    title="Writing Timeline documentation"
    image="http://simile.mit.edu/images/csail-logo.gif"
    >
    A few days to write some documentation for <a href="http://simile.mit.edu/timeline/">Timeline</a>.
    </event>

<event 
    start="Jun 16 2006 00:00:00 GMT"
    end="Jun 26 2006 00:00:00 GMT"
    title="Friend's wedding"
    >
    I'm not sure precisely when my friend's wedding is.
    </event>

<event 
    start="Aug 02 2006 00:00:00 GMT"
    title="Trip to Beijing"
    link="http://travel.yahoo.com/"
    >
    Woohoo!
    </event>
 </data>
```

I'm having a problem with LOAD XML, I save their XML example file in the same place that the template but when I refresh the page I get this error:

Failed to load data xml from test.xml
NOT FOUND

I would like to known if anyone knowns why or to solve this. My idea was to save my data into some XML file but perhaps it isn't the best solution.
If someone has better ideias to make time lines I would also appreciate.

Thanks!

Comment: You probably need to show some of the code you are using. A test.xml exists in the same directory as your test script?

Comment: Yes the template and the test.xml are in the same folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried with a complete url path for the xml? something like "http://localhost/text.xml".. or maybe a relative path "./test.xml"

Comment: ok..Now I have another mistake:
Caught exception: TypeError: v1 is null

Comment: When I tried to open in Chromium Web Browser I get this one:
Caught exception: TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null

Comment: hmmm why dont you put your page online and give us the link?, it'd be easier to find out the problem

Comment: Well I don't think you will see the link cause I'm in a internal server..But I can send you the files so you could see in your computer, if your interested, obviously.
Sorry, I started learning programming only a few months ago so I'm still a newbie..

Comment: i've tested a simple page with your code, and it doesn't show any error... this is the page http://jleanoma.perso.info.unicaen.fr/testTimeline/timeline.php It works in your browser? take a look into the source code to see if everything is the same

Comment: well..yeah..yours work but mine don't..
The only difference is this: Timeline.loadXML("/media/test.xml", function(xml, url) { eventSource.loadXML(xml, url);
I have to save the file into the media folder so that apache could see her.. I'm working in django..

Comment: done! 
If I remove these lines:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
 <?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="/TBDBsite/media/timeline.css"?>

it work.
Thanks!

Comment: wow great!! i was breaking my head trying to reproduce the error.. just as a reference, i think the problem is that Smile parses an XML file and that could cause some problems, the message i got was "XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal", that's why it's better to work with JSON in JS =)

Comment: I've never work either in XML or JSON.
But now that I was able to see the example, I want to use my data, that are models from django. Probably I will need to use loops or some queries..
Would you recommend doing this in XML or JSON? Since I have to learn anyway, better been something nice :P

Answer (score 3):

The reply, is rather late, but the error results from the data file including the xml declaration. The timeline widget only excepts an xml commencing with

```
<data>
```